# JavaScript new this.constructor(); => SyntaxError: missing ] after element list

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have some classes:

```
class Sample{
    static createSelf() {
        return new this.constructor(1, 2);
    }
}

class AnotherClass extends Sample {
    constructor(a, b) {
        this.c = a+b;
    }
}

ac = AnotherClass.createSelf();
```

How do I do this?

This concrete example gives me `SyntaxError: missing formal parameter`, although in my original code (500 lines), when I have `new this.constructor()`, I get `SyntaxError: missing ] after element list` pointed at the first line (the formal parameter error is pointed at line 1, too). I know it is because of this line, as when I replace it with a normal class name, it works. There is no Array initialization close. The error cannot possibly mean:

> There is an error with the array initializer syntax somewhere. Likely there is a closing bracket ("]") or a comma (",") missing.

from 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Missing_bracket_after_list

UPDATE
original code:

```
class Participant {
    constructor(origin, destination, number, startDate, endDate) {
        ...
    }

    static restore(save) {
        const participant = new this.constructor(
            new Marker(save.originLocation, this.getMarkerOptions(true, save.isDriver, save.number)).addTo(map),
            new Marker(save.destinationLocation, this.getMarkerOptions(false, save.isDriver, save.number)).addTo(map),
            save.number,
            save.startDate,
            save.endDate
        );

        return participant;
    };
}

class Driver extends Participant {}

d = Driver.restore(saveObject);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<del>If the error is pointing to the first line, then the syntax error is **before** the code you posted here.</del>

Turns out the reason for this error is that `this.constructor` refers to [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) which will evaluate one of the arguments passed to it as code. Since you are not passing JavaScript code to the it, you are getting a syntax error.

Example (open your browser's console):

```js
new Function({});
```

---

However, there are two problems with the code you posted here as well.

**`this` inside static methods**

The value of `this` depends on how a function is called. Static methods are called as methods of the *constructor* function, therefore `this` refers to the constructor function. In your example, with `AnotherClass.createSelf();`, `this` refers to `AnotherClass`. Therefore `this.constructor` refers to `Function`. I don't think that's what you want. I guess you want

```
class Sample{
    static createSelf() {
        return new this(1, 2);
    }
}
```

It looks like you thought `this` would refer to an *instance* of the class, but how could it? You haven't created one yet.

**`this` inside constructors**

When a class extends another class, you **always** have to call `super()` inside the constructor before you are accessing `this`:

```
class AnotherClass extends Sample {
    constructor(a, b) {
        super();
        this.c = a+b;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added a portion of the original code, as it I couldn't to replicate the `SyntaxError: missing ] after element list` on jsfiddle (I'm using also external libraries, e.g. 'leaflet'). So the solution is, as you say, that `this` refers to the parent object of the static function, the constructor function.

Comment: But it's strange that changing `const participant = new this.constructor(...` to `const participant = new this(...` eliminates (on my machine) syntax error, which even does not make sense in this case.

Comment: Ahhh. I get it. As I said, `this.constructor` refers to `Function`. Now, [that function expects a very specific set of arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), namely `new Function('list of parameters', 'code')`. Now I think that it tried to evaluate the second argument as code, but the string representation of that value isn't valid JavaScript code, so it threw a syntax error.

Comment: oh. Minimal example: `new Function({})`

Comment: my first two parameters were objects